# ¿Cómo optimizar este conversor de moneda?

Tags: javascript, html, input

Hola estoy practicando JavaScript y cree este convertidor de monedas. De pesos chilenos a Dolares y viceversa.
creo que tiene mucho código y se podría optimizar mucho, ustedes como lo optimizarían o lo mejorarían, me ayudaría bastante sus opiniones :)

```js
const deClpADolar = () => {
    let dolar = parseFloat(0.0012);
    var inputclp = document.getElementById('inputClp');
    var inputusd = document.getElementById('inputUsd');
    var declpausd = document.getElementById('convertirClpUsd');
    declpausd.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (inputclp.value >= 1) {
            parseFloat(inputusd.value = (inputclp.value * dolar + " dolares"))

        } else {
            alert("ingresa Un numero")
        }
        var limpiar = document.getElementById('limpiar')
        limpiar.addEventListener('click', () => {
            inputclp.value = ""
            inputusd.value = ""
        })

    })
}
deClpADolar()
const deDolarAClp = () => {
    let dolar = parseFloat(843, 31);
    var inputclp = document.getElementById('inputClp2');
    var inputusd = document.getElementById('inputUsd1');
    var declpausd = document.getElementById('convertirUsdClp');
    declpausd.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (inputusd.value >= 0.1) {
            parseFloat(inputclp.value = (inputusd.value * dolar + " Pesos"))

        } else {
            alert("ingresa Un numero")
        }
        var limpiar = document.getElementById('limpiar')
        limpiar.addEventListener('click', () => {
            inputclp.value = ""
            inputusd.value = ""
        })


    })
}
deDolarAClp();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solucion limpia y reusable es siempre una buena idea, aca le dejo un ejemplo.

```
var CasaDeCambio = function() {
        this.tipoDeCambio = "";
    };

    CasaDeCambio.prototype = {
        setTipoDeCambio: function(tipoDeCambio) {
            this.tipoDeCambio = tipoDeCambio;
        },

        convertir: function(cantidadDeDinero) {
            return this.tipoDeCambio.convertir(cantidadDeDinero);
        }
    };

    var OtraFormaDeCalcularLaConvercion = function(tasaDeCambio) {
        this.convertir = function(cantidadDeDinero) {
            // calculos...
            return "$45.95";
        }
    };

    var CambioChileno = function(tasaDeCambio) {
        this.convertir = function(cantidadDeDinero) {
            // calculos...
            if (cantidadDeDinero <= 0) {
               throw new Error ("No hay");
            }

            return cantidadDeDinero * tasaDeCambio;         
        }
    };



    // log helper

    var log = (function() {
        var log = "";

        return {
            agregar: function(msg) { log += msg + "\n"; },
            mostrar: function() { alert(log); log = ""; }
        }
    })();

    function run() {   
       // No voy a entrar en detalles de como capturar los valors desde el html
       // Deberias tener un checkbox para invertir los valores

        var inputclp = document.getElementById('inputClp');
        var inputusd = document.getElementById('inputUsd');
        // Falta la conversion de los inputs to float pero eso es algo que es simple para usted

        // No debe cambiar por eso const
        const tasaDeCambioADolar = parseFloat(843, 31);
        const tasaDeCambioAChileno = parseFloat(0.0012);

        var dolarAChileno = new CambioChileno(tasaDeCambioAChileno);
        var chilenoAdolar = new CambioChileno(tasaDeCambioADolar);


        var casaDeCambio = new CasaDeCambio();

        dolarAChileno.setTipoDeCambio(dolarAChileno);
        log.aggregar("Pesos Chilenos: " + casaDeCambio.convertir(inputusd));

        chilenoAdolar.setTipoDeCambio(chilenoAdolar);
        log.agregar("Dolares: " + casaDeCambio.convertir(inputclp));        

        // Los inputs no deben borrarse al calcular
        log.mostrar();
    }
```

Espero este ejemplo le ayude a solucionar su problema.

Comment: También lo sería dejar de usar var y pasar a Let y en ciertos casos incluso const

Comment: Es necesario utilizar POO para una funcionalidad de este tipo? Si bien puede ser un ejemplo y una forma de abarcar el problema válida, siento que confundiría más al OP si no conoce el paradigma